# Is there a way to declare notification names without repeating oneself?

Tags: swift

When declaring notification names, is there any way to avoid mistakes like this?

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let userHasLoggedIn = Notification.Name("userHasLoggedIn")
    //oops! developer forgot to change the literal...
    static let userHasLoggedOut = Notification.Name("userHasLoggedIn")
}
```

I am hoping for some kind of way to use the variable name as the notification name without having to re-type it. Something like this:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    //wishful thinking??
    static let userHasLoggedIn = Notification.Name(#fieldname)
    static let userHasLoggedOut = Notification.Name(#fieldname)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery).

I haven't used it but it's a code generator that uses templates to generate boilerplate code.

You could create a template or rule (sorry, don't know the actual terms) that converts `userHasLoggedIn` into `static let userHasLoggedIn = Notification.Name("userHasLoggedIn")`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use enumerators with a String like so:

```
enum Names: String {
    case logIn = "userHasLoggedIn"
    case logOut = "userHasLoggedOut"
}
```

Then in your code, you can say:

```
static let userHasLoggedIn = Notification.Name(Names.logIn.rawValue)
static let userHasLoggedOut = Notification.Name(Names.logOut.rawValue)
```

Comment: The question is asking how to avoid copy and paste errors in the string literal value. This does not address that question.